# Magento 2.4.5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, local-storage

I have updraded Magento from 2.4.0 to 2.4.5 and now in the product page, there's an error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')**

```
update: function (sections) {
        var sectionId = 0,
            sectionDataIds = $.cookieStorage.get('section_data_ids') || {};

        _.each(sections, function (sectionData, sectionName) {
            sectionId = sectionData['data_id'];
            sectionDataIds[sectionName] = sectionId;
            storage.set(sectionName, sectionData);
            storageInvalidation.remove(sectionName);
            buffer.notify(sectionName, sectionData);
        });
        $.cookieStorage.set('section_data_ids', sectionDataIds);
    },
```

line 167 in file Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js

```
storage.set(sectionName, sectionData);
```

Comment: Any luck solving this? I have the exact same error but on checkout page which just has spinning wheel and a blank page.

Comment: May be this could fix the error https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/213550/78366

Answer (score 1):

Afternoon all,

I found the cause for my issue for the same error on step 1 of the checkout with a patchable solution, please see the links below:

Useful information and debugging help: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined -- upgrade from 2.3.4 to 2.4.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/328363/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-remove-of-undefined-upgrade-from-2)

Resolved my issue by applying patch from: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/31940/files

The issue is caused by customer-data.js file which the above git hub patch updates. I hope this update helps anyone with a similar issue.

Comment: Just to confirm that applying this patch worked for me. Thanks for this information!